# Получение исходного кода из скомпилированного файла

Tags: c++, linux, g++, gdb

Пусть у меня есть C++ код. Я компилирую его командой:

```
g++ -g code.cpp -o code.o
```

Теперь мне нужно получить исходный код обратно, имея только `code.o`.

Я точно не уверен, что это очень просто, но я знаю, что gdbtui (и, скорее всего, gdb) как-то достаёт этот код и использует его для вывода пользователю.

**Задача:**
Получить исходный код из файла, скомпилированного с флажком -g

Comment: gdb хранит всю информацию о скомпилированных символах (функциях, глобальных переменных и т. д.). За кодом же он обращается к исходному файлу. Это можно заметить, если изменить файл и запустить отладчик - он выругается на то, что исходники новее бинарника.

Comment: @Ancient, были такие мысли, но так и не проверил. Спасибо.